# How do I fix the error while building the Vapor app?

Tags: swift, vapor

When I create my project, everything looks good, vapor tells me "Project demoNew has been created!", but after that I try to build it and i have an error

Error looks like:

error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission."
VaporToolbox/exec.swift:55: Fatal error: result 1
Illegal instruction

I tried to use sudo, and I have same result..

ubuntu 20.04 64bit
swift 5.5.1

Comment: What's the output of `swift build`?